# How to connect to MSSQL using tokens or encrypted strings

Tags: sql-server

I have two questions that i cannot find an answer for.
I have already searched a lot.

**The situation**
I will deploy C# winforms application to a client, the app have users who should connect to my database on whatever host is to validate they are already logged in to prevent the same user from being logging again from other PCs, so basically when the user logs in the app sent a command to my DB that the XYZ user has been logged in.

**The questions**

*First one and the most important one:* how to access my MSSQL server from the client side without putting in the connection string because as you know someone may decompile the app and find the user and password, so basically how to TOKENIZE or ENCRYPT the sql connection string (may then will be decrypted in SQL server but i don't know how too)

*The second question is*: how effectively implement the above situation, as you know it is easy to send commands that hey I'm logged in and hey I'm logged out (when the user click log out) BUT... What if the electricity went off? the app will not have the chance to send log out command to my server and therefore the user will be LOGGED IN in my server even he is actually not.

Hopefully i do describe my questions properly.

Comment: You won't find answers because the way to secure access to SQL Server is to *put a server of your own* in between the clients and the database server. That can manage authentication, etc, and keep it's own connection string(s) safe because they're not used by the clients.

Comment: If you could limit SQL server being hosted inside customer domain (AD), then you could use windows security to access SQL server - this way you don't need to store authentication info at all. This doesn't solve double logon problems; for this you could use application locks. In my opinion such logon restrictions are worthless anyway - you will have hard time to convert your application into web or stateless one, you need to process any network glitches properly and other similar troubles.

Comment: For your first question: Nothing in your question rules out windows authentication. You should never use SQL Authentication (user/password) if you can use windows authentication. For your second question: what are you really trying to do? You're right in that these manual Mutex solutions all suffer from getting "stuck" if there is an unanticipated state. So what are you trying to do?